# TensorFlow Dynamic RNN - How to take mean over all LSTM states ignoring zero vectors?

Tags: tensorflow

I understand that `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` handles variable lengths by copying the last valid state to the end of the output vector and pads the LSTM output with zero vectors.

In this case, i would like to do a mean over all LSTM states with ignoring the zero vectors. How can I do this in TensorFlow?

Alternatively, how do you take a mean over a list of vectors while masking the zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a sum instead of a mean and then divide by the lengths to get the mean.

Answer (score 1):

Calcuate the sum, and then divide by the number of nonzero entries, which you can count using [`tf.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/count_nonzero)